# unknown directive "content_by_lua_file" in Nginx, Linux

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit

After installing everything -- nginx, Lua, LuaJit, openresty, etc -- and starting nginx, I get this:

```
unknown directive "content_by_lua_file" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site.com
```

What did I forget? Should have been enabled Lua support somehow when I was installing nginx? How?

My script will run on LuaJit and the OS is Arch Linux

Comment: Yes, nginx must be build with Lua support (turned off by default)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff how presicely on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install openresty and nginx separately. Openresty is a modified nginx, not a library, and its executable is also called `nginx`. Try typing `whereis nginx` into the command prompt and see if you have more than one executable in your path, and most likely you'll find that you're starting plain nginx instead of openresty.

Unless you want to have openresty and nginx running in parallel (for which there really is no good reason, unless it's to meet some third-party security standards or something like that), just uninstall nginx (and to be 100%, uninstall and reinstall openresty too), then try again.

If that still doesn't work, try calling `nginx -V` and tell us what it says.

---

EDIT:

You can also type

```
which nginx
```

to see exactly which executable is used and

```
ls $(which openresty)
```

to see if it's a symlink to somewhere or

```
file $(which openresty)
```

to see if it's a binary or a bash script that runs something else.

That should cover the most common indirections and help figure out exactly which nginx binary *actually* gets called.

Also try if there's an `openresty` binary, using the commands mentioned above.

Comment: `whereis nginx` ---> `nginx: /usr/bin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx /opt/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8.gz
`

Comment: I've uninstalled nginx. Now  nginx of openresty isn't  visible via "systemctl nginx status" and simple "nginx". Is this the correct behavious of openresty?

Comment: As I asid, try renistalling openresty (maybe even purge it) to make sure normal nginx didn't mess with its configurations. If you want you could create a symlink to `/opt/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx` as `/usr/local/bin/openresty`, then you can just call `openresty` and it should work.